# Flutter - How manage TextStyle in one file 'text_style.dart' function to call in another view?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a custom TextStyle with some constructors such as Color and fontWeight, so later in the screen view the style for the font and size is fixed, but only the color and fontweight can be customized,

```
    class TextStyles {
  final Color fontColor;

  const TextStyles({
    this.fontColor = Colors.black;
  });

  static const TextStyle buttonText = const TextStyle(
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
      color: fontColor,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
      fontSize: 14.0
  );
}

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  ....
  final Function onPressed;

  const CustomButton({
    Key key,
   ...
    @required this.onPressed,
    this.textSize = 14.0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CreateBlueButton = FlatButton(
        color: background,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyleCustom,
        )
    );

    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 53),
      ...
```

Answer (score 8):

Here what you need:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTextStyle extends TextStyle {
  final Color color;
  final FontWeight fontWeight;
  final double size;
  final String fontFamily;

  const MyTextStyle({
    @required this.color,
    @required this.fontWeight,
    this.size = 14,
    this.fontFamily = 'Montserrat',
  })  : assert(color != null && fontWeight != null),
        super(
          color: color,
          fontWeight: fontWeight,
          fontSize: size,
          fontFamily: fontFamily,
        );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The approach I am using is:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  MyApp() {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.white
      )
    );
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: _configureThemeData(),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }

  ThemeData _configureThemeData() {
    return ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
            headline: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35.0,
                height: 0.8,
                color: Colors.red,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
            title: TextStyle(fontSize: 35),
            subtitle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
            body2: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.white)));
  }
}
```

and call this text style using:

```
Text('I AM HEADLINE IN STYLE',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline)
```

Answer (score 0):

when make a text style usually lot of theme, diferen size, and color, so
why not make a custom widget like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class TextWhite14 extends StatelessWidget {
  final data;
  const TextWhite14({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      data,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 14.0
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then just call it somewhere else like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:parent_app/model/text_style_putih_14.dart';

class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyScreenState createState() => _MyScreenState();
}

class _MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: TextWhite14(
          data: "This is your text with white colour and 14 font size",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or even better full customize with more parameter :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyTextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;
  final double size;
  final double color;
  const MyTextWidget({Key key, @required this.data, this.size, this.color}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      data,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: color ?? Colors.white,
        fontSize: size ?? 14.0
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

@required mean it must cannot be null, and now you can just call color, size, without type style : TextStyle() ...

Comment: Why not just create a class contains all of needed TextStyle instead of create a StatelessWidget which return a Text?